# Stop filtering WordPress function wp_insert_post

Tags: wordpress

I have to make a few minor changes to a website built in WordPress, and I came across some problems with the wp_insert_content function.  This function sanatizes input, taking some HTML tags completely out (like ) and deleting attributes on others.  I would like to switch this off, and everywhere I find a link to http://pp19dd.com/2010/06/unfiltered-wp_insert_post/ where the solution is to add

```
'filter' => true
```

to the posts input array.

This article is from 2010 though, and from what I found an extra line was added in 2011 (http://web.archiveorange.com/archive/v/TDTh42SUwDEc1GFmSrvU).  This line reads:

```
unset( $postarr[ 'filter' ] );
```

and is called right after merging the input with the defaults, and before sanitizing.  It seems to me that this line cancels the 'filter' => true statement above.  Indeed, sanitizing happens if the line is there, and disappears if the line is taken out.

So the easy solution would be to add the 'filter' => true and delete the extra line in the function.  Problem though is that I have no idea where else the function is used, and I wonder if it's smart at all to hack right in the WP code.  An update of WP would restore it anyway.  So ... is there any other way to stop this function from sanitizing the input?

Comment: On behalf of anonymous User... **Edit** This seems to do the trick: `kses_remove_filters(); wp_insert_post( $my_post ); kses_init_filters();` Problem solved!

Comment: Didn't work for me in this way either.

Comment: I'm testing with the last wordpress and it allows me to insert html tags (images,iframes whatever). Which tag is it exactly removing? In your example above your example got stripped away!

Answer (score 9):

It is possible that some other plugin may be trying to sanitize the content, in such case remove all the filters is the only option, try the following:

```
remove_all_filters("content_save_pre");
$post_id = wp_insert_post($post);
```

Other possible filter tags are:

- `pre_content`
- `pre_post_content`
- `content_pre`
  Try them one by one also if it does not work.

Comment: This might work, but removing all the filters is a really, really bad idea. There are filters to stop PHP being injected into the database so you should find the right filter to remove and use `remove_filter()`

Comment: i want to add  post title in the form of <font color=red><b>Post title</b></font> but its reject  font tag

Answer (score 0):

i'm also in the process of importing posts with s in the content body.
i've been searching all morning for a solution, there have been some discussions on the topic. so far

```
kses_remove_filters();
```

has done nothing for me, neither did commenting these two lines:

```
unset( $postarr[ 'filter' ] ); // overrides 'filter' => true since 3.0 i guess
$postarr = sanitize_post($postarr, 'db');
```

in wp_insert_post() in post.php (defaults at line 2704).

there's another interesting bit at line 2874:

```
$data = apply_filters('wp_insert_post_data', $data, $postarr);
```

which seems like could be the source of our troubles, but i'm too much of a newbie to figure this out on my own.

really, truly, desperately need help! oh, and i can't comment, sorry for the spam action.
i would like to keep this thread open and find a solution.

I guess it worked before i posted, but the content i was importing already had HTML tags stripped
the easiest workaround would be to manually overwrite the content after inserting the post, but this only works for isolated environments or for importing

```
$wpdb->update($wpdb->posts, array("post_content"=>$content->content), array("ID"=>$postid), array("%s"), array("%d"));
```

anyhow,

```
remove_all_filters("content_save_pre");
```

did the trick!

Comment: Re-iterating what I said on the other answer: Removing all the filters is a really, really bad idea. There are filters to stop PHP being injected into the database so you should find the right filter to remove and use `remove_filter()`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need this

**wp_filter_post_kses()**

*Sanitize content for allowed HTML tags for post content.
Post content refers to the page contents of the 'post' type and not $_POST data from forms.
This function expects slashed data.*

To prevent its effect on the content, insert the code in function.php your topic.

```php
remove_filter('content_save_pre','wp_filter_post_kses');
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**