# wordpress wp_insert_post lose data

Tags: xml, wordpress

I built a ajax Wordpress interface for visitor to create post, something like this:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_front_view_post', 'front_view_post' );
function front_view_booking() {
    $my_post = array(
       ...
       'post_content'  => '<name>Jack</name><age>13</age>'
       ...
   );
    wp_insert_post($my_post)
    ...
}
```

The content of the posts contains xml tags. The code worked fine if I logged as admin in the browser.

However if I use the function as a general visitor, without any login. All the xml tags are removed when creating the post, and only "Jack13" were stored in the post.

Could anybody help to look at this issue?

Comment: May be your answer is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20424322/stop-filtering-wordpress-function-wp-insert-post

Comment: Yes, this is the answer. Thanks very much.